# What is a "declarative format"?

Tags: coding-style

[The Twelve-Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/) says:

> Use declarative formats for setup automation, to minimize time and cost for new developers joining the project

What does "declarative formats" mean?

Comment: A few thousand bucks for the authors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is declarative programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129628/what-is-declarative-programming)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A declarative format is one in which you declare the intention/end-result of the program, instead of how it should be arrived at. Declarative code is typically comprised of statements that invoke high-level functions or abstractions with clear human-readable intent. Conversely, imperative code is comprised of statements that clearly impart their effects on the program state without reference to any high-level goal.

More succinctly, ***declarative*** code conveys the **why**, and ***imperative*** conveys the **how**.

The following code is the `Makefile` for a hypothetical program `hellomake`. This program uses the abstractions provided by `make` to define the build procedure without specifying the the implicit low-level details. The `Makefile` only needs to specify the compiler, the source directory, and the file dependency structure, and then uses the `make` abstractions to fill in all the boilerplate based on this program structure. This is considered a `declarative` format because the statements convey high-level meaning without specifying low-level actions.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = hellomake.h

# Build an object file for each of the dependencies.
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

# Build the hellomake program using the hellomake and hellofunc object files.
hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
    gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o -I.
```

The following Python script performs the same task defined in the `Makefile`, but because Python is far more general-purpose than `make`, all of those build details need to be performed explicitly. These explicit program actions clearly describe how the program will alter the build environment, but cannot describe how they contribute to the overall goal of compiling the program without auxiliary explanation (e.g. comments). This is considered an `imperative` format because the low-level actions are clearly defined and conveyed to the programmer.

```
CC = "gcc"
CFLAGS = "-I."
DEPS = ["hellomake.h"]
def make_o_file(o_file, deps):
    #don't recompile if it exists & is current
    c_file = "%s.c" % os.path.splitext(o_file)[0]
    if (os.path.exists(o_file) 
            and is_newer(o_file, c_file) 
            and all(is_newer(o_file, dep) for dep in deps)):
        return

    #else actually compile it
    compile_c_file(CC, code_file, o_file, CFLAGS)

if target == "hellomake":
    make_o_file("hellomake.o", DEPS)
    make_o_file("hellofunc.o", DEPS)
    link_o_files("hellomake", ["hellomake.o", "hellofunc.o"])
```

Both imperative and declarative formats serve valuable purposes in programming. The Wikipedia on [declarative programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) might be useful for additional details.

Comment: I'm not sure that the examples were well chosen. The examples expect everyone to understand some weird syntax. Even for experienced developers like me, it was hard do grasp the difference between both examples without re-reading them many times.