# Play 2.5 What is akka.stream.Materializer useful for?

Tags: scala, playframework

I started to use Play 2.5 recently, and I was wondering what the purpose of doing the following was:

```
@Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer)
```

I had several pieces of code not working and solved that issue thanks to this, but I still don't see what the materializer is doing.

Thanks

Comment: Play 2.5 is using Akka Streams as ReactiveStreams implementations, so the materializer is required. See [Streams Migration](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/StreamsMigration25).

Comment: There is also the [akka streams documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#Stream_Materialization) that explains in depth what the materializer actually is and what it does.

Comment: What were these "several pieces of code" doing?

Comment: By instance : 
class A@Inject()(implicit val mat: Materializer, cache: CacheApi, wsClient: WSClient, configuration: play.api.Configuration)
didn't work before I did Materializer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Materializing means producing the results of a [graph](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html?language=scala)

A materializer makes [actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html?language=scala) execute a graph to produce those results.

A graph, in its simplest form, consists of a source that provides elements, and a sink that consumes elements.

Here's a source that provides a range of integers (in this example, integers are our elements):

```
val source = Source(1 to 10)
```

And here's a sink that sums all the integers it gets from a source:

```
val sink = Sink.fold[Int, Int](0)(_ + _)
```

We connect source and sink to get a graph:

```
val graph = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.right)
```

Mind that *no computation*, addition in our case, is performed when creating a graph.
The code is [declarative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129628/what-is-declarative-programming), the graphs describe how we want to transform our data but it is someone else's job to actually perform the computation: Graphs are [blueprints](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html?language=scala#stream-materialization).

Now, what about the materializer? The materializer takes action when we run the graph:

```
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
val futureResult = graph.run()
```

When we `run()` the graph, the materializer takes the graph and makes actors execute the data transformations specified in the graph; in this example, that's adding integers.

It might be helpful to imagine the graph as a blueprint to build a house, the materializer as the foreman looking at the blueprint, telling the builders how to actually build the house according to the blueprint. The builders in this analogy correspond to actors in Akka.

The reason why several pieces of your code now work, is that with the materializer you provide a way to execute graphs. Graphs are heavily used in [Akka HTTP](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/?language=scala) which Play uses for HTTP requests and responses.

The [WSClient](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#Making-a-Request) you mentioned in your comment uses graphs to perform its requests and thus needs a materializer.

---

Here's a full example of creating and running a graph:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source}

object Graphs extends App {
  // The start of our simple graph. It provides elements, integers in our case
  val source = Source(1 to 10)

  // The end of our graph. It processes the source's elements
  val sink = Sink.fold[Int, Int](0)(_ + _)

 /*
  * Connect source and sink.
  * Keep only the output values (i.e., the graph's right side).
  * Note that this is declarative: no result is computed until we run the graph.
  */
  val graph = source.toMat(sink)(Keep.right)

  // The system coordinates actors and provides threads for them
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  // The materializer makes actors execute graphs
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  // Running the graph means that the materializer assigns actors to execute
  // the graph from start (source) to end (sink)
  val futureResult = graph.run()

  // Use the actor system's execution context, which provides threads,
  // to print the result of running the graph
  implicit val executionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher
  futureResult.foreach(res => println(s"Result of running the graph: $res"))

  actorSystem.terminate().foreach(_ => println("System is shut down"))
}
```

Put this in your `build.sbt` to make Akka's stream library available in your code:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.19"
```

[Here's more](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html?language=scala) on sources and sinks.

Comment: The example with the house and the builders made things a lot clearer for me! Ty!

Comment: One more question: Given, say a single Play project with various classes that utilize Akka streams (e.g., various MongoDB DAOs), do we instantiate a new materializer per class instance, or can we just have one that can be shared?  If shared is fine how we'd share such a materializer?

Comment: @ManabuTokunaga: I haven't used Scala in quite a while but I think it's possible and reasonable to share a materializer between classes. As to how to share the materializer: You can pass the materializer as a constructor parameter to those classes that need a materializer.