# How do I test Play REST API with Json BodyParser?

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, playframework-2.6

I would like to write a simple test for a controller, which accepts a json body. But as soon I add the `parse.json` BodyParser to the Action my Tests cannot be compiled anymore. 
The Setup is basically the plain play-scala-seed project.

Error:

```
[error] ... could not find implicit value for parameter mat: akka.stream.Materializer
[error]       status(home) mustBe OK
[error]             ^
```

`HomeController`:

```
def index() = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok
}

def json() = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  Ok
}
```

`HomeControllerSpec`:

```
class HomeControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerTest with Injecting {
  "HomeController POST" should {
    "answer Ok" in {
      val controller = new HomeController(stubControllerComponents())
      val home = controller.json().apply(FakeRequest(POST, "/"))
      status(home) mustBe OK
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two issues with the code in question regarding `stubControllerComponents` and `FakeRequest` calls.

[`Helpers.stubControllerComponents`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c2f7ef8478e4e02d2fa15741756c4092c7195fdc/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L589) by default constructs `ControllerComponents` with [`NoMaterializer`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c2f7ef8478e4e02d2fa15741756c4092c7195fdc/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L655) which simply throws an exception when used, so we need to provide an actual materializer as follows:

```
       implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()(ActorSystem())

       Helpers.stubControllerComponents(
         playBodyParsers = Helpers.stubPlayBodyParsers(materializer)
       )
```

The second issue is with `FakeRequest` where we need to provide a body as follows (otherwise we get `4xx` error) :

```
FakeRequest(POST, "/json").withBody(Json.obj("name" -> "Jon Doe"))
```

Taking into account the above we can write the complete test as follows:

```
class HomeControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerTest {
  "HomeController POST" should {
    "answer Ok" in {
       implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()(ActorSystem())

       val controllerComponents = 
         Helpers.stubControllerComponents(
           playBodyParsers = Helpers.stubPlayBodyParsers(materializer)
         ) 

       val controller = new HomeController(controllerComponents)

       val fakeRequest = 
         FakeRequest(POST, "/json").withBody(Json.obj("name" -> "Jon Doe"))

       val home = call(controller.json(), fakeRequest)

       status(home) mustBe OK
    }
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2023**

The apply method `ActorMaterializer()` is deprecated and today the recommended way to build a materializer instance is the following.

```
implicit val materialzer = SystemMaterializer(ActorSystem()).materializer
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you need to inject a materializer in your controller:

`class Controller @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer) { ??? }`

Comment: It works fine when I run the Application but not in tests. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888253/play-2-5-what-is-akka-stream-materializer-useful-for and added implicits for actorSystem and materializer in my test class. It's compiling but always returns 400 without my method ever called.