# Is unix's 'cp' command declarative or imperative?

Tags: imperative-programming, declarative-programming

I'm having a discussion with a coworker, who insists cp is declarative. To me, it seems very imperative. It's an instruction we are asking the computer to do, not a definition or declaration. For it to be declarative, instead of:

```
cp a.zip b.zip
```

you might have:

```
b.zip = a.zip
```

Does anyone have any opinions on this?

Comment: Neither. It's a command (it might be built-in into the shell), but `cp` is not a programming language.

Comment: The command itself is neither. Instead you should probably as the broader question if the *shell scripting language* is declarative or imperative.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a discussion on terminology, not a *practical* problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using those terms at a level where the two have little distinction. For instance, if I were making a user interface for a program and had some file saying

```
Logo:
  Title: Cool UI
  Color: Green
```

That is a declarative representation of my ui. It is data that represents what I want the computer to do. If I were to instead make my ui by using code like

```
l = Logo()
l.add(Title('Cool UI'))
l.add(Color('Green'))
ui.render(l)
```

That would be an imperative representation of my ui. I am telling the computer what to do each step of the way. When we talk about the cp command, its worth thinking about what the difference between an "imperative" and "declarative" version would be. On the one hand, you cant get more imperative than telling the computer to

```
 cp a.zip b.zip
```

Which from a certain perspective is just like saying "hey increment this register" or "hey move whats at this memory address to this memory address", which in assembly is just

```
mov r0, r1
```

That being said, if you were to describe in data what you wanted to do you would say something like

```
copy-paste: a.zip b.zip
```

Which, take out the colon and shorten the name and you get

```
cp a.zip b.zip
```

TL;DR at this level of specification, there is basically no difference between imperative and declarative

Answer (score 0):

The cp(1) syntax itself is declarative because you define **what** you want to accomplish without specifying **how** it needs to be done. Which, by the way, means your both examples are declarative.

You may also want to take a look to a [wider discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129628).

Comment: By that definition, can you name *anything* that wouldn't be declarative? When I'm writing in assembly language, I say that I want to take the number stored in one register, treat it as a memory address, and load the 8 bytes at that location into another register. That's *what* I want to happen. *How* the processor does that (through timing, control signals, etc) aren't in what I write.

Comment: `cp a.zip b.zip` Being placed in the shell context the command shall be considered imperative. Which, of course, doesn't make it's syntax imperative either.