# Imperative vs Declarative in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the concepts of imperative vs declarative styles through python.

From my understanding the definitions of imperative and declarative are

```
imperative - code all the steps in the desired outcome
declarative - code the desired outcome without the steps
```

For example:

would this be considered imperative?

```
L = []
for i in range(5):
    L.append(i*2)
```

and would this version be considered declarative?

```
L = list(map(lambda x: x*2, range(5)))
```

Comment: Declarative would be: `L = createList()`. They are both imperative to me! Your declarative example does explain it all step by step, like you imperative example does.

Comment: @ElisByberi, I don't really agree that that's declarative either -- at least not in Python, where it tells the interpreter to *immediately* run the function `createList` and assign its results to `L`; contrast to languages where that statement where `L = createList()` simply means that `L` needs to have some properties *at a later time, if and when it's evaluated*. The short form here is that Python simply *isn't* a declarative language -- one can build declarative languages on top of it, but those are separate languages, not Python.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `L = createList()` is as declarative as it can get. All (pure) functional and logic-based programming languages are also declarative. Functions that have no side effects at all are called purely functional. However, Python is not a declarative **only** language like SQL.

Comment: @ElisByberi, as declarative as it can get *in Python*, but my point is that that's not actually meaningfully declarative at all (compared to Haskell, Prolog, CLIPS, etc). That said, one can certainly use Python to build an interpreter for a different language that *is* declarative, but that seems rather far afield from what the OP is asking.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I do agree with you! I did provide the example to show 
 to OP what declarative would look like (no steps at all, I just want a list).

Comment: @ElisByberi I'm sorry to say that if your example was valid, every procedural language would be declarative.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed! As you rightly say, Python can be used to create declarative solvers, planners or frameworks (Django views for instance), but the language itself has no declarative features.

Comment: @ManuValdés Common declarative languages include those of database query languages (e.g., SQL, XQuery), regular expressions, logic programming, functional programming, and configuration management systems. Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including procedural, object-oriented, and functional programming. Therefore, the example I did provide is as declarative as it can get.

Comment: @ElisByberi, ...however, if "as declarative as it can get" (in Python) is not something that would be widely recognized *as* declarative by people who work in declarative languages, describing it simply as "declarative" is liable to be misleading to folks coming in without prior background to understand the implications of the "as it can get" qualifier in the context where it's used.

Comment: @ElisByberi, it's just a call to a function. Judging by your comment I don't think you understand what declarative means.

Comment: @ManuValdés You may need to read (or re-read) this article [Declarative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming). It's just that simple! Remember, Haskell is a purely functional programming language but it does not make it more functional than Python. Again, Python supports multiple programming paradigms, including procedural, object-oriented, and functional programming. E.g. Java is a general-purpose programming language that is class-based, object-oriented. Also, Java is not more nor less class based programming language than Python. I'm out!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Common declarative languages include those of database query languages (e.g., SQL, XQuery), regular expressions, logic programming, functional programming, and configuration management systems. That says it all. I'm out!

Comment: @ElisByberi, you're preaching to the choir; I'm a regular practitioner with XQuery, Datalog, Clojure (not declarative, but functional, and certainly amenable to building declarative DSLs), and an occasional dabbler with Haskell, so I don't know why you felt the need to recite dictionary definitions at me.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy "as declarative as it can get": You may not think it is declarative but it isn't going to be less nor more declarative than other declarative languages." Have a nice day!

Comment: For a countervaling argument, see http://michaelrbernste.in/2013/06/20/what-is-declarative-programming.html, describing a continuum between "less declarative" and "more declarative" languages.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and other readers, https://stackoverflow.com/q/129628/2430448

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193528/discussion-between-elis-byberi-and-charles-duffy).