# Why call-by-value evaluation strategy is not Turing complete?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, computer-science, turing-complete

I'm reading an article about different [evaluation strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) (I linked article in wiki, but I'm reading another one not in English). And it says that unlike to `call-by-name` and `call-by-need` strategies, `call-by-value` strategy is *not* [Turing complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete).

Can anybody explain, please, why is it so? If it's possible, add an example pls.

Comment: @KennyTM: I'm trying to find the source in references at the end of the article. I can give you a link if you'd like but it's in Russian.

Comment: A Russian article is better than nothing. Not me, but someone may be able to read Russian.

Comment: There are of course many languages that use call-by-value that are turing complete. I suspect that the article talks about a specific language that would not be turing complete if it used call-by-value (though I can't quite imagine what such a language would look like).

Comment: So called call-by-value languages are not totally call-by-value: they use special forms for control structures. I'm not aware of any language based on CBV lambda-calculus without special forms. Is there any?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I dispute the claim** in the article you are reading.  (I'm not getting paid for this, so I'm going to provide a suggestive argument, not a proof.)

It is well known that, at least under normal-order reduction (aka call by name), the pure lambda calculus is Turing-complete.  But if we look at John Reynolds's seminal paper [Definitional Interpreters for Higher-Order Programming Languages](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.5892&rep=rep1&type=pdf), we can see that Reynolds discusses at length the difference between call by name and call by value.  A critical part of the argument is that in order to make a proper distinction, we can transform a program into *continuation-passing style*.  The CPS transform is different for call by need and call by value, but the resulting transformed terms can be evaluated in either style.

So here comes the argument: write a lambda-calculus program that simulates a Turing machine, then CPS transform it using the CBN transform, and you can evaluate the resulting code using a CBV reduction strategy.  Bang!  Turing-complete.

In practice, I bet you can write a CBV program to emulate a Turing machine; it's probably enough to pick a suitable fixed-point combinator, like Θ for example.  (The more famous Y combinator works only under a call-by-name reduction strategy, i.e., normal-order reduction.)

**Disclaimer:** I haven't studied lambda calculus in ages, and I'm sure there are several details wrong in the argument above.  But I'm confident in the substance.  It wouldn't be the first time I spotted something blatantly wrong in online resources about programming-language theory.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense without reference to some specific language, but I'll try my best to answer with respect to the Untyped Lambda calculus.

The existence of a call-by-value fixed point combinator (i.e. "Y combinator") for the untyped lambda calculus seems to refute the basic claim (see: [Fixed Point Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator)).  The existence of such a combinator breaks strong normalization, which suggests that there is at least one language that is turing complete that uses a call-by-value evaluation strategy.

Much more likely to affect the turing-completeness of a language is the existence (or lack of) a type system.  For example, the simply-typed lambda calculus cannot encode a fixed point combinator, and is strongly normalising (i.e. all well-typed terms reduce to a value), however, this is true irrespective of the evaluation strategy employed.  Rather, it is a consequence of the type system.