# SQL Query - Group column as XML

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this in MS SQL Server.

[image: SQL Table]

I want to query this table so that the TagId and Value columns are grouped together by EntityId and displayed as XML.

Sample query result

[image: Sample Result]

The XML structure is not fixed. Any type of XML structure will do.
Is it possible?

Comment: Almost everything is possible in SQL (it is [Turing complete language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete)). If you post sample data https://dbfiddle.uk instead of pictures I could prepare solution(simple FOR XML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT o.EntityName,
       o.EntityId,
       (SELECT (SELECT i.TagId "Tag/@id",
                       i.Value "Tag/@value"
                       FROM elbat i
                       WHERE i.EntityId = o.EntityId
                       FOR XML PATH(''),
                               TYPE)
               FOR XML PATH('Tags')) Value
       FROM elbat o
       GROUP BY o.EntityName,
                o.EntityId;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/72b5b/1)

Answer (score 0):

This not seems like a better method. But it gives solution:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(id int, TagId int, Entityname Varchar(100),EntityId INt, value VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(1,1,'TravelerProfile',856,'Finanace')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(2,2,'TravelerProfile',856,'A')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(3,3,'TravelerProfile',856,'pune')

 select
   distinct Entityname, EntityId,
    stuff((
        select ',' + 'OpenTag'+ CAST(u.id AS VARCHAR)+'MidTag'+ u.value+'EndTag'
        from @Table u
        where u.EntityId = EntityId
        order by u.EntityId
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as Value
INTO #temp
from @Table
group by Entityname,EntityId

SELECT Entityname, EntityId
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(VALUE,'OpenTag','<Tags><TagId = "'),'MidTag','" value="'),'EndTag','"/></Tags>'),',','') Value
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**Output:**

```
Entityname      EntityId    Value
TravelerProfile 856         <Tags><TagId = "1" value="Finanace"/></Tags><Tags><TagId = "2" value="A"/></Tags><Tags><TagId = "3" value="pune"/></Tags>
```