# Is circuit composed of NAND/NOR turing complete?

Tags: logic

According to another answer, it seems yes, but it looks like any binary counter implementation uses some kind of "clock".

So, is NAND/NOR still turing complete without "clock" component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an overview of the topic, [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7284/1911064) is helpful.

A [combinational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinational_logic) circuit composed of `NAND` and `NOR` gates without feedback loops is not a Turing complete machine. It lacks memory and it cannot execute a program with loops and conditional branches. The output values only depend on the current input values. Disregarding transient signal changes, such a circuit exhibits a purely static behaviour.

However, [SR flip flops](https://www.multisim.com/help/components/sr-flip-flop/) as basic elements of sequential logic can be built out of `NAND` gates. Additional combinational logic determines, how the state machine transitions from one state to the other. Such a finite state machine is still not Turing complete, as it has a finite amount of memory. See [this related post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/110998).

So, an infinite `NAND`/`NOR` circuit could be a candidate to analyze for Turing completeness.